# JavaScript function called with button onclick, fails with onload

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to use an external JavaScript function in the body tag: `<body onload=function()>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mqttws31.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Long.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ByteBufferAB.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ProtoBuf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload ="heartbeat()">

<h2>A demo for showing the pub/sub between clients and the message     broker</h2> <h3>IoTGateway</h3>
Topic :
<input type="text" name="pub"/>
Message:
<input type="text" name="pub"/>
<button onclick="connect()">
    Connect
</button>
<br>
<button onclick="publish()">
    Publish
</button>
<br>

<h3>BluetoothID</h3> Topic:
<input type="text" name="sub"/>
<button onclick="heartbeat()">
    Subscribe
</button>
<br>
<p id = "test"></p>
<p id="sub"></p>
<script>
        function heartbeat() {
            alert("hello");
            try{
            MqttPlugin.subscribe({topic: "$EDC/plugin"});
            }
            catch(err){
            alert(err.message);
            }
        }
       /* try{
        MqttPlugin.heartbeat({topic: "$EDC/tum/B8:27:EB:A6:A9:8A/HEARTBEAT-V1/mqtt/heartbeat"});
        }
        catch(err){
        alert(err.message);
        }*/



        function publish() {

            MqttPlugin.publish({
            topic:"$EDC/plugin",
            data:"Mqtt data"

            });
        }

        function subscribe() {
            MqttPlugin.subscribe({topic: "$EDC/plugin"});
        }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The function `heartbeat` is called when I call with the event `onclick` but fails with `onload`. In case of `onload`, it throws an error MqttPlugin not defined. Is it because by the time it calls the function, the js files are not loaded? Could someone help me fix this?

Comment: You never closed your function `}`.

Comment: where did you close function , and script tag ?

Comment: Sorry, I have not updated my code. I have made those corrections. But still it doesnt work.

Comment: where is the script tag located that references the plugin?

Comment: Is the script tag wrapped in the head tag ?

Comment: You have written the function correctly. Where exactly are you importing the javascript for MqttPlugin is important. Either paste the script import code here to help us more or try changing its location.

Comment: Thanks Obscure Geek. I have now pasted the whole code.

Comment: @AnkurBhatia your logic looks correct. I put together a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/0utrohvv/2/) trying to simulate the issue, but it seems to work as intended.  Which reference is for the plugin?

Comment: shouldn't onload="heartbeat" be onload="heartbeat()"? This is not going to resolve your actual error though.

Comment: Ya, i changed that.. But still not working.

Comment: @Jason The plugin reference is inside the javascript file cordova_plugin.js. The problem is that the function is successfully called when I use it with button onclick, but fails with onload-

Comment: @AnkurBhatia I see that your `window.onload` is inside the heartbeat function.  Is this intended?  It seems like this should be outside of the heartbeat function.  I also updated my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/0utrohvv/3/) with your exact example and it is working as intended, are you getting any other errors?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake while adding code here. Thats not the actual problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your basic aim here is to subscribe to a topic automatically when the page is loaded. You can either try:

```
</script>
<style onload="heartbeat()"></style>
</body>
```

Or try changing the order of imports.

The first suggestion is just an hack not a full proof solution though.

The basic problem is that the heartbeat function is getting called before cordova_plugins.js is getting loaded. So either delaying the function call or loading the file early will do the trick.

**Edited:**

This jQuery method might just be the solution:

```
$( window ).load()
```

Please find documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: Exactly.You are right. The Function getting called before the js file is loaded. Is there some way I can check if all my js files have been loaded completely?

Comment: You might find [this](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/how-to-detect-when-an-external-library-has-loaded) useful.
Also check the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this should solve the problem. Will give a shot.